# STL unordered containers iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Which kind of iterators -
bidirectional or random access
are used in the STL unordered containers like unordered map?

Comment: Bidirectional iterators are used for associative containers.

Comment: @Kunal Unordered associative containers do *not* have the requirements of associative containers.

Comment: @DyP yes, of course :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A *general container* is only required to have an iterator of at least the *forward iterator* category [container.requirements.general].
- The requirements for *unordered associative containers* [unord.req] don't contain a specification for the iterator category.
- The requirements for *(ordered) associative containers* do not apply.

All four current unordered associative containers explicitly list their iterator categories in their individual descriptions, e.g. [unord.map.overview]/1

> The `unordered_map` class supports forward iterators.

All four only support forward iterators, fulfilling the minimum requirement for containers only.